# Can I delete the system-reserved partition on my RAID (non-system-drive)

Tags: windows-7

I have reinstalled my system as follows:
1 x 400 GB HDD -> system drive
4 x 1000 GB HDD -> RAID 10

After the installtion of Windows 7 Enterprise x64 is finished, I have a 100 MB NTFS system-reserved partition on each of the 2 disks (the 400 GB HDD and the RAID disk).
I would like to delete the system-reserved partition on my RAID disk.

Can I delete that partition without screwing up my new installation?

Edit1: Okay, I found out that this partition contains files for system-recovery and bitlocker.
But I thought that it'll be created only once.

The actual system-drive was my drive for movies, music and so on. I didn't format or partition it before I reinstalled win 7 (because my important files will be moved to the raid-disk). Could it be, that the system-reserved drive on my actual system-drive is from an earlier installation? (The actual system-drive containted the bootmgr from my previous win 7 installation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself as follows:

First I downloaded EasyBCD to find out, which of the two system-reserved partitions is used to boot.
Then I moved it to my system-disk (it was on the raid-disk).
After that, I had to change boot-priority of sata-disks in BIOS to my system-disk as first drive.
After that, I deleted that partition on my raid-disk.

That's all.